# Does it fit into the definition of a 'Default Constructor'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a class named Flower and use a default constructor to get the following output:

```
Output:
Name of this flower: Rose
Color of this flower: Red
Number of petal: 6
=====================
Name of this flower: Orchid
Color of this flower: Purple
Number of petal: 4**
```

This is my code:

```
class Flower:
    
    def __init__(self):
        pass
         
            
flower1 = Flower()
flower1.name="Rose"
flower1.color="Red"
flower1.num_of_petal=6
print("Name of this flower:", flower1.name)
print("Color of this flower:",flower1.color)
print("Number of petal:",flower1.num_of_petal)
print("====================")
flower2 = Flower()
flower2.name="Orchid"
flower2.color="Purple"
flower2.num_of_petal=4
print("Name of this flower:",flower2.name)
print("Color of this flower:",flower2.color)
print ("Number of petal:",flower2. num_of_petal)**
```

After running my code I'm getting the desired output. But is my default-constructor part correct? P.S. This no homework question. It's a sample question just for practice

Comment: As your constructor does nothing, you don't even have to write it, remove the `__init__` method, and unindent the `pass` ant it'll work the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

> default constructor :The default constructor is simple constructor which doesn’t accept any arguments.It’s definition has only one argument which is a reference to the instance being constructed. [src](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/constructors-in-python/)

Since you did not code explicitly a constructor (`__init__`), it uses the default constructor which is empty, and thus does not accept any arguments other than the instance which is being constructed.

Comment: still correct, it is equivalent to the first version

Comment: if this solves your question, please mark it as fixed

Answer (score 0):

What's the point of the class at all if you define and assign all its properties outside the class? Here's a much more sensible object-oriented approach where we define the properties of the object *inside its constructor!*. This way, *all objects* of the `Flower` class are guaranteed to have those properties. The idea is to [encapsulate](https://stackify.com/oop-concept-for-beginners-what-is-encapsulation/) everything that is related to `Flower` objects inside the `Flower` class:

```
class Flower:
    # This is the default constructor. It initializes all properties to some default values
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "NoFlower"
        self.color = "NoColor"
        self.petals = 0

#    This is what a custom constructor with optional arguments would look like
#    def __init__(self, name="NoName", color="NoColor", num_petals=0):
#        self.name = name
#        self.color = color
#        self.petals = num_petals

    def print(self):
        print("Name of this flower:", self.name)
        print("Color of this flower:", self.color)
        print ("Number of petal:", self.petals)
```

Then, you can create flowers with your default constructor:

```
flower1 = Flower()
flower1.print()
```

Output:

```
Name of this flower: NoFlower
Color of this flower: NoColor
Number of petal: 0
```

Or, you could specify the values once you create the flower

```
flower1 = Flower()
flower1.name="Rose"
flower1.color="Red"
flower1.petals=6
flower1.print()
```

Output:

```
Name of this flower: Rose
Color of this flower: Red
Number of petal: 6
```

In a real-world example, you'd probably not use the default constructor and instead, use something like what I suggested that takes optional arguments. With that definition of `__init__(self, name="", color="", num_petals=0)`, you could do:

```
flower2 = Flower("Orchid", "Purple", 4)
flower2.print()
```

Which would give you

```
Name of this flower: Orchid
Color of this flower: Purple
Number of petal: 4
```